# How to delete a set of rows from one table based on info in another table java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, join

I have the following two tables:

```
Orders
    _id
    customer
    note
    ready

OrderTransactions
    _id
    orderid(links to orders._id)
    product
    quantity
```

What I want to do is delete all `OrderTransactions` that have an order where ready is equal to "y"

I've seen the join mysql statements to do this, but I don't know how to implement those joins in the `mDb.delete statement` below

```
public OrdersDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
private static final String ORDERS_CREATE =
    "create table orders (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "customer text not null, note text not null, export text not null);" ;
private static final String ORDERPRODUCTS_CREATE =              
    "create table orderproducts (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " 
    + "orderid integer not null, product text not null, quantity text not null);";
public boolean deleteOrderProductsAllReady(long orderId) {


    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_ORDERPRODUCTS, ***criteria***, null) > 0;
}
```

I think the query should look like this:

```
DELETE ordtran
FROM OrderProducts AS ordtran
INNER JOIN Orders AS ord
ON ordtran.orderid = ord._id
WHERE [ready="y"]
```

but I don't know how to put that into the above `mDb.delete` syntax.

Comment: You have no foreign key linking your `orderproducts` table's `orderid` to `order`'s `_id`; is it on purpose? Also, why the leading underscore for primary key columns? Composite primary keys do exist, so this won't help matters.... And where is the transactions table?

Comment: Delete from orderTransactions where orderid in (select _id from orders where ready='y')

Comment: thoitbk - I really don't know how to put that sql in the ***criteria*** parameter of the mDb.delete function. That's my big problem. 

fge - no, I don't have a foreign key, not sure how to implement it.

Comment: fge - That gave me the info I was looking for. Implemented the foreign key with cascaded delete. Thanks!!